iptable-save command not showing any output
When i run  iptables-save command on Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS it not showing default firewall chain rules when i run this other linux example centos or redhat i am able to see below output:
[root@rhel-8-50805-client ~]# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Fri May 10 10:03:11 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [33772:226622349]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [28942:9992818]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri May 10 10:03:11 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Fri May 10 10:03:11 2024
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [33772:226622349]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [28942:9992818]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri May 10 10:03:11 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Fri May 10 10:03:11 2024
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [33773:226622837]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [28942:9992818]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri May 10 10:03:11 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Fri May 10 10:03:11 2024
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [33773:226622837]
:INPUT ACCEPT [33772:226622349]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [28942:9992818]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [28942:9992818]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri May 10 10:03:11 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Fri May 10 10:03:11 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2:552]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:64]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [871:61737]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [871:61737]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri May 10 10:03:11 2024


Your details (22.04.3 & 20.04.4) show you're using rather old systems without security & other fixes applied; I suggest you apply fixes asap.  Do you actually have a question though?  as your description just shows a difference (without any question).

What have you done to suppose there may be something to display in iptables-save ? otherwise did you try iptables-legacy-save ?

have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687857/what-is-the-relationship-or-difference-among-iptables-xtables-iptables-nft-xt

@guiverc my system is up to date, the question is when i run command iptables-save showing some output on rhel7 rhel8 centos7 centos8 but not showing any output on ubuntu 22.04.3 & 20.04.4.

@dominix
What have you done to suppose there may be something to display in iptables-save ?
The output i have shared in my question is from rhel8 which i am not able to see in ubuntu machines u can also check by running this command on rhel and ubuntu machine

you asked this question on a ubuntu forums q&a. So do not digress, just explain us what did you do as iptables command related to expect that there may be something to display in iptables-save ? because in some case you may need iptables-legacy-save.

Ubuntu 22.04.3 is a 22.04 system which has not had all security/updates applied by definition.. ie. 22.04 updated to 22.04.4 prior to official release of 22.04.4 ISOs, the release being 22.04 & the last .3 being a reflection of update status (*and also an ISO which has updates applied, ie. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/ says "As usual, this point release includes many updates and updated installation media has been provided so that fewer updates will need to be downloaded after installation."  with the updates the difference)

I have tried to run iptables-legacy-save but its not showing any output as well, both commands i have tried to run on 24.04 LTS version as well but no any output, I want to get all tables output and want to compare with some other commands/files
